# plot command for two variables

Tags: plotting

Do you have an idea how to plot this: if I have x and y axises and I want to determine points {x1,y1) as a line in xy, which is the best plot command to do this.

```
x = {0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
     0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
     0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
     0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`};
y = {0.075, 0.0755`, 0.076`, 0.0765`, 0.077`, 0.0775`, 0.078`, 
     0.0785`, 0.079`, 0.0795`, 0.08`};
x1 = {0.027000000000000003, 0.027000000000000003, 
     0.027000000000000003, 0.027000000000000003, 0.027000000000000003`, 
      0.027000000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003, 0.027000000000000003, 
     0.027000000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003, 0.0275`};
y1 = {0.075, 0.0755`, 0.076`, 0.0765`, 0.077`, 0.0775`, 0.078`, 
      0.0785`, 0.079`, 0.0795`, 0.08`};
```

I tried ListLinePlot, but it doesn't show me the whole x scales
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) to create coordinate pairs, and then [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot) them:

```
ListLinePlot[{Thread[{x,y}], Thread[{x1,y1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also `Transpose`

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Is there a way to show just the orange line in the same axises scales.

Comment: Maybe `ListLinePlot[{Thread[{x, y}], Thread[{x1, y1}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {None, Automatic}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried      ListLinePlot[Thread[{z1, x1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.025`, 0.03}, {0.075, 0.08`}}] and it works.